# React native : Flatlist inside scrollview

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

My goal is for this entire block to be scrollable.
I tried all kinds of ways to achieve the goal but without success.
I tried with `ListHeaderComponent` and moved the entire top view to it and it didn't work.
And I also tried `<FlatList nestedScrollEnabled />`
And it didn't work either.
What is the correct way to reach the scroll?

**I come from here :**

```
const renderAccordians = () => {
    const items: JSX.Element[] = [];
    areaData.forEach(item => {
      items.push(<Accordian item={item} key={item.title} />);
    });
    return items;
  };
```

**To here :**

```
return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onClickFather()}>
          <MaterialIcons size={24} name={data.checked ? 'check-box' : 'check-box-outline-blank'} color={'black'} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={[styles.title]}>{data.title}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.row} onPress={() => toggleExpand()}>
          <MaterialIcons name={expanded ? 'arrow-drop-up' : 'arrow-drop-down'} size={30} color={'black'} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.parentHr} />
      {expanded && (
        <FlatList
          data={data.data}
          numColumns={1}
          scrollEnabled={false}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
            <View>
              <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.childRow, styles.button]} onPress={() => onClick(index)}>
                <MaterialIcons
                  size={24}
                  name={item.checked ? 'check-box' : 'check-box-outline-blank'}
                  color={'black'}
                />
                <Text style={[styles.itemInActive]}>{item.key}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <View style={styles.childHr} />
            </View>
          )}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
```

Comment: why did you disable `scrollenabled`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `FlatList` will be part of an `Accordion` component, you "can't" embed the `ExpandButton` inside the `Flatlist > ListHeaderComponent` ... cause It'll simply hide the whole `FlatList` along with it's `Header` when you collapse your accorddion...

`keyExtractor` is also missing in your `FlatList` .. I added `index` as a `key` here which is not recommended BTW, you better use a unique field in your `listItem` like `id`...

```
    return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1}}> // <<--- Look here
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onClickFather()}>
          <MaterialIcons
            size={24}
            name={data.checked ? 'check-box' : 'check-box-outline-blank'}
            color={'black'}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={[styles.title]}>{data.title}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.row} onPress={() => toggleExpand()}>
          <MaterialIcons
            name={expanded ? 'arrow-drop-up' : 'arrow-drop-down'}
            size={30}
            color={'black'}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.parentHr} />
      {expanded && (
        <FlatList
          data={data.data}
          numColumns={1}
          scrollEnabled={true} // <<--- Look here
          keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()} // <<=== Look here
          contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}} // <<--- Look here
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
            <View>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={[styles.childRow, styles.button]}
                onPress={() => onClick(index)}
              >
                <MaterialIcons
                  size={24}
                  name={item.checked ? 'check-box' : 'check-box-outline-blank'}
                  color={'black'}
                />
                <Text style={[styles.itemInActive]}>{item.key}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <View style={styles.childHr} />
            </View>
          )}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
```

Comment: its not works .

Comment: Add more explanation, plz about "What went wrong"... cause "not works" won't be enough for anyone who want to help...

Comment: I edit my question in up.
If this is not enough for you then tell me and I will throw away the 2 full components .

Comment: I'd be great if you add a screenshot of what you get after applying my answer...

Comment: The accordion simply disappears and is not shown

Comment: Checkout the edit...

Comment: Now I see several accordions.
Can you open a private chat with me so I can show you what I have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250011/discussion-between-hend-el-sahli-and-emma).

Comment: ok so now i just move the
<View style={{ flex: 1}}>

but its not scroll now

Comment: I brought you V, but you should know that it still doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

If it does not work, I think you should create a component and use map datalist to render all the items and putting them into the ScrollView tag.

```
<ScrollView
                style={styles.messageContain}
                ref={ref => {
                  this.scrollView = ref;
                }}
                {data.data.map((item, index) => {
                  return <YourComponent key={index} data={item} />;
                })}
              </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you show me please how you implement your idea in my code ?